# importing a text file using pgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have just downloaded pgAdmin 1.14.3 in an effort to import, query, and manage large textfiles.  These textfiles are either quote comma quote delimited or tab delimited (they come as quote comma quote and I edited many for use with another software).  While version 1.16 allows an import function, it has not been released yet and I am wondering how to import data into a newly created table using pgAdmin.

The text files range from 12MB to 2GB, so I'm looking for a comprehensive solution that would not involve importing row by row.  I tried this with phppgadmin, but ran into file size limitations embedded in the php.ini file (separate post) and am trying this as a possible workaround.  I'm a little new to SQL, so not really sure of all the commands possible at my fingertips.  Any helps is appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can issue a `COPY` statement, like this:

```
COPY table_name (column_name)
FROM 'd:\test.sql';

Query returned successfully: 6 rows affected, 31 ms execution time.
```

See the documentation here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html

Note that I did not test this in PgAdmin for large files, but using psql I have never seen a case where the file had been too big for `COPY`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch - this is helpful, but I am having trouble and I suspect it is due to permission issues - my text file is on my CPU downstairs and the server cpu with postgreSQL is upstairs.  I didn't think that matters, but maybe it does?  I get two seperate errors depending on if I use COPY or \copy.  COPY produces "syntax error at or near "C" (referring to the path name) and \copy produces "no such file or directory"

Comment: thank you very much for your help.  The error was actually on my end and when I took a fresh start today, I found missing columns.  I fixed the error and used the following commands to import successfully:  \copy test FROM 'c:\test\test.txt'

Comment: furthermore, I was able to import the largest of the files - 2.6GB by creating a csv version and importing using WITH CSV HEADER as specified by the like you gave me. Thanks!